Orientation of 1st order 2D boundary mesh is counter-clockwise but 2nd order one is clockwise, any deep reason?
Consider this toy example:
<< NDSolve`FEM`;

visual[order_] := 
 With[{mesh = ToElementMesh[Triangle[], MeshOrder -> order, MaxCellMeasure -> .1], 
       nlst = ElementShapeFunction[LineElement, order][s]}, 
  With[{index = mesh["BoundaryElements"][[1, 1]], coords = mesh["Coordinates"]}, 
   ParametricPlot[nlst . coords[[#]] & /@ index, {s, -1, 1}] /. 
    Line[a_] :> {Arrowheads[0.1], Arrow[a]}]]

visual /@ {1, 2}


As we can see, the orientation of mesh is counter-clockwise when MeshOrder is set to 1, but is clockwise for MeshOrder -> 2. I've tested several 2D graphic primitives, the orientation seems to be always like this.
This design looks inconsistent to me (and has caused trouble when I'm trying to implement a numeric line integral solver). Is there a deep reason for this design?
BTW, it's worth mentioning that if we replace ToElementMesh with ToBoundaryMesh, the problem no longer exists.

There are three 'orders' to be synchronized and passed by options to an FEM: MeshOrder, InterpolationOrder and IntegrationOrder. The numbers seem to vary from 1 to 5. The internal implementation has to fullfil the axioms of Grassmans algebra wrt to the passage from an global oriented volume form to its approximation by a set of oriented set polytopes, egdes, veritices, such that Stokes is true by cancellation of all inner integrals by antisymmetry.
